# How to Check Node is Expand or Collapse in Apache Echarts Tree

Tags: javascript, echarts, apache-echarts

I want to check node is Expand or Collapse on click.

I checked click event but did not get any flag for Collapse or Expand

```js
    chart.on('click', e => {
      // want to access here 
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

`chart.on('click', func(params) {})`

The params provide access to the **collapsed** flag.

I didn't have any luck using this outside of the scope of `chart.setOption()`.

Since it's inside, you need to add **"this"** as the context for access-

`chart.on('click', func(params){}, this)`

Read more here- https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.on